# C++ lambda capture by value without declaring variable earlier

Tags: c++, c++11

Looking at the example on the page:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate

It uses a lambda:

```
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [n = 0] () mutable { return n++; });
```

the variable `n` is not declared anywhere prior to the lambda.

Having tried this snippet in MSVC 14 and GCC 9.1, it does work on both.

Try to find a reference to this behaviour at:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

but cannot find anywhere where it says that new variables can be declared in the capture region of a lambda.

Is this expected behaviour? What are the restrictions if it is?

Comment: "Having tried this snippet in MSVC 14 and GCC 9.1, it does work on both." not sure about MSVC but for gcc you need to enable C++14 or newer something like  `gcc -std=c++14`

Comment: @Slava FWIW, GCC 6 and above default to C++14: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html

Answer (score 6):

In the reference you link to, it's in the [lambda capture section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture), item number 3 in the list.

And from further down (in a "since C++14" section):

> A capture with an initializer acts as if it **declares** and explicitly captures a variable declared with type `auto`

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

Which explicitly explains the behavior of that capture clause.